# How to load both .env file and the OS environment variables in golang

Tags: go

```golang
err := godotenv.Load(".env")
if err != nil { panic(err.Error()) }

shell := os.Getenv("SHELL")
fmt.Println(shell)
```

I set the `SHELL=/bin/zsh` in my `.env` file, but it seems the OS first looks for the given key in the OS environment variable list, and then it checks the `.env` file. Is there a way to separate these two?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Yes there is a way to solve this problem .
the `github.com/joho/godotenv` has a function called `Read()` . you can load your .env file into a map data structure .

```
envFile, _ := godotenv.Read(".env")

envFileShell = envFile["SHELL"]
fmt.Println(envFileShell) // will be /bin/zsh (what you set in .env file)

osShell := os.Getenv("SHELL") 
fmt.Println(osShell) // will be whatever it is set in your operating system
```